# Wordpress/Apache - 404 error with unicode characters in image filenames

Tags: wordpress, apache, unicode

We've recently moved a website to a new server, and are running into an odd issue where some uploaded images with unicode characters in the filename are giving us a 404 error.

Via ssh/FTP, we can see that the files are definitely there.

For example:

http://sjofasting.no/project/adnoy

none of the images are working:

Code:

```
<img class='image-display' title='' src='http://sjofasting.no/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/ådnøy_1_2.jpg' width='685' height='484'/>
```

SSH:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx  836813 Aug  3 16:12 ådnøy_1_2.jpg

What is also strange is that if you navigate to the directory you can even click on the image and it works:

http://sjofasting.no/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/

click on 'ådnøy_1_2.jpg' and it works.

Somehow wordpress is generating

> http://sjofasting.no/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/ådnøy_1_2.jpg

and copying from the direct folder browse is generating

> http://sjofasting.no/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/a%CC%8Adn%C3%B8y_1_2.jpg

What is going on??

---

edit:

If I copy the image url from the wordpress source I get:

http://sjofasting.no/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Bore-Strand-Hotellg%C3%A5rd-12.jpg

When copied from the apache browser I get:

http://sjofasting.no/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Bore-Strand-Hotellga%cc%8ard-12.jpg

What could account for this discrepancy between:
%C3%A5 and %cc%8

??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unicode normalisation.

`0xC3` `0xA5` is the UTF-8 encoding for U+00E5 a-with-ring.

`0xCC` `0x8A` is the UTF-8 encoding for U+030A combining ring.

U+0035 is the composed (Normal Form C) way of writing an a-ring; an `a` letter followed by U+030A is the decomposed (Normal Form D) way of writing it. `å` vs `å`  - they should look the same, though they may differ slightly depending on font rendering.

Now normally it doesn't really matter which one you've got because sensible filesystems leave them untouched. If you save a file called `[char U+00E5].txt` (`å.txt`), it stays called that under Windows and Linux.

Macs, on the other hand, are insane. The filesystem prefers Normal Form D, to the extent that any composed characters you pass into it get converted into decomposed ones. If you put a file in called `[char U+00E5].txt` and immediately list the directory, you'll find you've actually got a file called `a[char U+030A].txt`. You *can* still access the file as `[char U+00E5].txt` on a Mac because it'll convert that input into Normal Form D too before looking it up, but you *cannot* recover the same filename in character sequence terms as you put in: it's a lossy conversion.

So if you save your files on a Mac and then transfer to a filesystem where `[char U+00E5].txt` and `a[char U+030A].txt` refer to different files, you will get broken links.

Update the pages to point to the Normal Form D versions of the URLs, or re-upload the files from a filesystem that doesn't egregiously mangle Unicode characters.

Think Different, Cause Bizarre Interoperability Problems.

Comment: Wow thank you for the response, that is really informative. It must be the problem as well because I had to download all the files locally first before copying them to the new server. (for some reason rsync was not working). I'll give scp a try first and hopefully that will take care of things. Out of curiosity though, how exactly do I get the Normal Form D version of these filenames? I'm just a bit confused as I am used to simply typing `å` with `opt+a`

Comment: Ok! SCP'ed all is fine now. (I remember, originally the old server didn't provide us with ssh/shell access). What a strange problem. Thanks for the help I was really getting confused with the whole situation. However my final question still stands, how can I ensure that I am using a universally compatible Form in the future when using a Mac?

Comment: I'm not sure what form opt+a will give you (I don't have my OS X VM here to check, but I'd suspect Normal Form D). But you can be sure that if you create a file on OS X, type opt+A in the filename, press Enter, then rename, the `å` there will be in Normal Form D, so you can copy and paste it to wherever you need that. One quick way to find out what you've got is to run Python at the command line and paste the character into a string: `>>> u'å'` - Python should respond by printing the string with Unicode escapes, so you'd get either `u'\xE5'` for NFC or `u'a\u030A'` for NFD.

Comment: When filenames on other systems, you have to make sure they're in decomposed form if you want them to be Mac-compatible. Unfortunately, although Windows and Linux both support composed and decomposed forms fine, their keyboard layouts default to typing the composed form.