# Apache rewriting my encoded filename with special characters

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I'm having a problem downloading files which have special characters in it like the "ñ" or "Ñ".

I'm applying rawurlencode() to every filename. But when I hit the route apache is rewriting my url.

```php
<td>
  <a href="{{asset("storage/" . rawurlencode($fyi->file))}}" target="_blank">{{$fyi->name}}</a></td>
```

When I inspect the href in the a tag I got the correct URL encoded route like this picture below.

[a tag with encoded url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcroA.png)

But when I hit the link, the encoded is missing

[missing encoded after hitting the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG7F7.png)

And here my apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xxx.com
    ServerAlias xxx.con

    DocumentRoot /home/dev/xxx.com/public
    AllowEncodedSlashes On


    <Directory /home/dev/xxx.com/public>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxx.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxx.com-access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =xxx.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It's just the browser displaying it nicely to you. Check the network tab in the browser devtools or your server log and you'll see it's actually encoded. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCm7D.png

Comment: Oh, you're right, okay so that isn't the problem so I have to open a new question to see why it isn't founding every file tha has a "ñ" ??

Comment: Linking raw files through an HTTP server becomes a lottery when you use non-ASCII characters such as `ñ`. The layers involved (file system, Apache, PHP...) will not always agree on the encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the browser displaying it nicely to you. Check the network tab in the browser devtools or your server log and you'll see it's actually encoded.

[image: screenshot]

---

The real problem is something else - Unicode normalization. It's a complicated topic, see [this](https://serverfault.com/a/449219) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206426/1871033) answer for an explanation.

We can see that this is the solution to your problem because while your [original link](https://linkedprop.roilands.com/storage/1609944044-AUTORIZACION%20DE%20ALQUILER%20TRADICIONAL%20CABA%20NU%C3%91EZ.docx) doesn't work, [this one](https://linkedprop.roilands.com/storage/1609944044-AUTORIZACION%20DE%20ALQUILER%20TRADICIONAL%20CABA%20NUN%CC%83EZ.docx) works. I replaced `%C3%91` (which is one character "N with tilde") by `N%CC%83` which are two characters - an N followed by a "combining tilde" - `Ñ` (1 character) vs `Ñ` (2 characters) - looks the same but is encoded differently!

tl;dr: There are several ways to represent the same thing in Unicode. You are getting a link that has `Ñ` as single character `U+00D1 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE`, but your actual file seems to have `Ñ` as two characters: `U+004E : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N` followed by `U+0303 : COMBINING TILDE`.

[image]

To ensure that it works, it's best to make sure that the "normalized" representation is used everywhere, that is the form "NFC" (there is also "NFD" which is what your filename currently has). Note that Mac tends to use NFD while other *nixes usually use NFC and this can be a problem if you are uploading files from a Mac without converting the filename in the process.

The solution is to run the `convmv` tool on your storage folder to convert the filenames of all the files:

```
convmv -r -i -f utf8 -t utf8 --nfc --notest .
```

Alternatively (or additionally) you could try and understand where the incorrect link comes from in the first place, but having NFD filenames on Linux is a recipe for bugs anyway, because you never know what library or client or whatever may make the mistake of accidentally normalizing the filename at some point - it can come back as a bug years later when you add some new feature, so it's best to make sure the filenames are using NFC in the first place.

---

Another option you may consider is having an index of file metadata in your database, and not storing the file with its actual filename (which could also lead to security vulnerabilities in case of any misconfiguration, by the way) but with some random ID as name, and then identifiying it by its ID and upon download returning the original name in the `Content-Disposition` header so the user gets the right filename at the end. To improve the user experience you could then create URLs like `/storage/<ID>/<nice-name>` where `<nice-name>` is just used for display purposes (to make the URL already show what file it is )and not used to identify the actual file.